# Set the background color of parents div padding in child-div

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want the grey section to be painted. To be exact, i want to paint the parents padding with that grey color by setting the div's background color.

Is something even possible by using css?

My HTML looks looks like that:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div>
          <img/>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <p class="no-margin">vs</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div>
          <img/>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="margin-top">
          </p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row bet-section">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="">
          <p class="no-margin">This section should be painted</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The corresponding padding for the parent div comes from:

```
.card .card-body {
    padding: 0.9375rem 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

My bet-section class looks like that right now, maybe I should change something inside here?

```
.bet-section{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: convert your code into a [mcve] by using the button with the bracket:`<>`;. You should note that in your HTML, there are several tags highlighted in red. While they may or may not correspond with your real code, we need common errors to be rectified so that we can better answer your question. So please correct the HTML by closing the red tags with its missing tags.

Comment: I read your question 2 times but I can't get to understand what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
`<div class="row bet-section">
  <div class="col-md-12 newclass">
    <div class="">
      <p class="no-margin">This section should be painted</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`

.bet-section .newclass{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't help me. The section just gets repainted with the color light grey.